# How to assign a group to new data using k means?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining

can we assign a group or cluster to a new data(test data) using unsupervised learning techniques? For expamle k means clustering.

Comment: By '*assign a group or cluster to a new test data*', are you implying semi-structured: #guiding. Or a you looking at outputting a group from `k-mean clustering` to a new data

Comment: A simple way is using nearest neighbors. You can fit a KNN model on the data and clusters obtained and predict the cluster assignment on unseen data. It's important to check that the new data follows a similar distribution because KNN considers the k closest observations regardless the actual distance.